# Possibility of syntax highlighting “dotless dotfiles” on GitHub

Tags: github, syntax-highlighting, dotfiles

I manage my dotfiles using Git and GitHub as many of you does. I name the original files without a dot (e.g. `zshrc`, not `.zshrc`) so that I can recognize them in Finder and make their symbolic links with a dot;

```
ln -s ~/.dotfiles/gitignore_global ~/.gitignore_global
ln -s ~/.dotfiles/zshrc ~/.zshrc
# and so on...
```

When I look their remote repository at GitHub website, the syntax highlight on my `gitconfig` and `gitignore_global` are invalid while others’ `.gitconfig` are properly colored. However, my `zshrc` has its syntax highlight though it does not contain a dot in its name.

I would like to highlight `gitconfig` and `gitignore_global` like `.gitconfig` and `.gitignore`. Is there any way to achieve this?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Internally, Github uses the [**Linguist library**](https://github.com/github/linguist) to determine the language statistics of your repository and for the syntax highlighting of your files, when browsing on Github website. However, as you remarked it, some syntaxes are not correctly detected, like your `gitconfig` and `gitignore_global` files, probably because the dot is missing in front of the filename.

To manually set syntax highlighting in your files, you can add an **emacs or vim modeline** in one the file's comment, anywhere in the file. The Linguist Library will detect it during the parsing of your file and the syntax highlighting of your choice will be enabled.

So, to precisely answer you question, if you want to syntax highlight your gitconfig file (that is as basic INI file syntax, you can add one of those modelines anywhere inside:

**vim modeline**:

```
# vim: set filetype=dosini:
```

**emacs modeline**:

```
# -*- mode: ini;-*-
```

This feature is documented on the [Linguist Github Page](https://github.com/github/linguist#using-emacs-or-vim-modelines).

For the `gitignore_global` file, i don't know about an available syntax highlighting for `.gitignore` files.